# How to Protect Flash from getting download

Tags: asp.net, flash

I am developing a elearning site and we have developed our courses in Flash. I want to know how we can prevent our courses from getting download from our site.Technology used for developing website is ASP.NET with C#.

Comment: Simple. Don't upload your courses to the site.

Comment: This is similar to asking how a person would be able to see a webpage without downloading it.  All web content must be downloaded to be viewed on a user's computer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are developing an e-learning site with a user login system, you can only give access to the courses to authenticated users that have rights to specific courses. If there is an unauthenticated / public request for a course file (swf, html, etc...) then refuse to serve that file to the client.

I'm sure there are other ways to accomplish this, but one way is to handle those file requests in your Global.asax, the general idea would involve using "Begin_Request", something like:

```
void Begin_Request(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.FilePath.Contains("yourprotectedpathname"))
    {
        if (check session if user is not logged in or does not have access)
            {
                Server.Transfer("404.aspx");
                return;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

You would want to store what users have rights to what courses in a database of course, and take advantage of Sessions

As the others have mentioned, anything the client can see can be downloaded. This method would simply limit the clients that have access to download your courses.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned users need to be able to download the content in order to view it. If your Flash files are standalone a user could pull the SWF files from their cache and run them locally or event post the files to another server to access them online.

If the content in the Flash files is read from a database via C# script that would make it much more difficult for users to replicate the structure.

I don't really recommend this method but you could hard-code the SWF files to only load from your domain, for example (AS3):

```
var myURL:String = "http://www.mydomain.com/";
//Check to see if the SWF is being loaded from mydomain
if (loaderInfo.url.slice(0, myURL.length) != myURL) {
    //If it isn't being loaded from mydomain, remove all displayobjects from stage
    while (numChildren > 0) {
        removeChildAt(0);
    }
}
```

This ActionScript would remove all items from the stage and just show a blank page if anyone tried to load the SWF locally or from another domain. I don't recommend this since you are hard-coding the domain into your Flash files. If you move the files to another domain the code would have to be updated. You would also need to account for variations in the URL (e.g. https, mydomain.com, www.mydomain.com etc.)